Class which can have instances python
I'm working on a logging libary. I want to transform my class, so that it's possible to have instances of it. My idea how it should look like is following:
from froggius import Froggius

instance = Froggius()
instance.debug('Hello World')

My class is simply built like every other; init function with some vars and other functions like debug or warning with some parameters. At this moment, when I run code like above, I'm getting this output:
[DBG] [03/04/2024 15:16:15] <froggius.logger.Froggius object at 0x1001eda00>

The class starts like that:
class Froggius():
    """
    Main class of Froggius
    Includes logging methods
    """
    
    def __init__(self, file_path=None, print_out=None) -> None:
        global glob_file_path, glob_print_out
        if file_path is not None:
            glob_file_path = file_path
        else:
            glob_file_path = None
        if print_out is not None:
            glob_print_out = print_out
        else:
            glob_print_out = None

    def debug(log_msg, file_path=None, print_out=None):
        """
        Writes logs, optionally to a file.

        Parameters
        ----------
        log_msg : str
            The message to be logged.
        file_path : str, optional
            The path to the file where the log should be saved, by default None
        highliting : bool, optional
            Whether the DEBUG tag should be highlighted with ANSI escape sequences, by default True
        print_out : bool, optional
            Whether the log should be printed to the stdout, by default True
        """


You have successfully done what you set out to do. (It would be hard to fail - classes can have instances by default. It's the core reason classes even exist.)

Your class doesn't actually use any instance state, and your debug method doesn't have a self parameter, but as far as being able to have instances of your class goes, you can indeed have instances.

As others have pointed out in the comments, classes in Python can already have instances by default.
Following this you can create as many instances as you would like, here's an example of how to do it from W3 schools:
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("John", 36)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)

As you can see it is pretty much the same thing you wrote, so just assign a variable to the object in order to create the instance like so:
instance1 = Froggius()
instance2 = Froggius()

and so on. For more information on Python classes I recommend checking out this page from the W3 schools website.

To ensure that the debug method is recognised as an instance method, you will need to pass self as the first parameter of the debug method and use self to access the instance's attributes and methods as needed.
As an example, your method will look something like this:
def debug(self, log_msg, file_path):
    if self.file_path:
       "Do Something" 


The debug method is already recognized as an instance method. The problem is just the missing parameter for the instance itself.
